# Proxy configuration for Chrome instance rather than system wide proxy configuration?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to specify proxy settings for my specific Chrome instance (I have two profiles, I would like one profile to be behind a proxy and the other not).

Chrome directs you to set proxy settings at the OS level rather than allowing for local configuration.

Is it possible to set proxy settings such that a specific instance of Chrome uses it?